# Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxxx.mysql.database.azure.com' (10061): Authentication failed

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, azure, dbforge

I have installed trial version of dbForge Fusion for MySql for my visual studio 2017 enterprise edition. Also I have created mySql server on azure portal. So I am using mysql server from microsoft as PaaS. On azure portal I have disabled the SSL requirement for connection to this database server. Now I am trying to connect to this mySql server from Visual Studio using Fusion => New Connection window.

I mentioned few details that I filled for connecting to mysql database as below -

1. Data source - auto selected as "MySql"
2. Connection - General tab I filled mysql server domain as -

   - Host - xxxx.mysql.database.azure.com
   - Port - 3306
   - User - usename@xxxx
   - Password - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
3. Connection - Advanced tab - auto selected values as it is.
4. Connection - Security - no selection
5. Connection - HTTP - no selection
6. Connection - Embedded - no selection

I have attached the screenshot of above details.

[image: Connection Settings]

When I click on Test Connection button, I am getting error as  - 
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxxx.mysql.database.azure.com' (10061): Authentication failed.

Please find the screenshot for the error.

[image: Connection Error]

I am able to connect this mySql server using same credentials using mySql workbench tool.

Can you please tell me what I am missing here?

Comment: Did you update the MySql service firewall to allow connections from the computer you're using?

Comment: Possible reasons - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-connecting.html

Comment: @DavidMakogon - Yes I added my machine ip in the allowed ip list of MySql firewall in Azure Portal.